# python - penalty game how to speed up element

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've created simple penalty game and all works fine but I want to improve it a bit. Goal moves on sides itself and want I want to do is speeding it up when scored. I understand when dx is negative it must be += 1 and if dx is positive it must be opposite so += -1. I thought about for loop for dx in range(-270, 0, -270) and the second one for prositive variables. I'm beginner in python and programming itself, so I appreciate any advice. I want to speed up SL, SP and P. Those objects create the goal.

```
import turtle
import time

    sd = 0.1
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.title("karne")
    wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
    wn.tracer(0)

    #pilka

    ball = turtle.Turtle()
    ball.shape("circle")
    ball.color("green")
    ball.speed(0)
    ball.penup()
    ball.goto(0, -275)
    ball.direction = "stop"


    score = 0
    miss = 0
    #scoring
    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    pen.speed(0)
    pen.shape("square")
    pen.color("white")
    pen.penup()
    pen.hideturtle()
    pen.goto(0, 0)

    #slupek lewy

    sl = turtle.Turtle()
    sl.shape("square")
    sl.color("white")
    sl.shapesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=1)
    sl.speed(0)
    sl.penup()
    sl.goto(-80, 270)
    sl.dx = sd

    #slupek prawy

    sp = turtle.Turtle()
    sp.shape("square")
    sp.color("white")
    sp.shapesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=1)
    sp.speed(0)
    sp.penup()
    sp.goto(80, 270)
    sp.dx = sd

    #poprzeczka

    p = turtle.Turtle()
    p.shape("square")
    p.color("white")
    p.shapesize(stretch_wid=7, stretch_len=1)
    p.speed(0)
    p.seth(90)
    p.penup()
    p.goto(0, 290)
    p.dx = sd

    score = 0
    miss = 0

    #function

    def right():
        x = ball.xcor()
        x +=20
        ball.setx(x)

    def left():
        x = ball.xcor()
        x -=20
        ball.setx(x)

    def shoot():
        ball.direction = "up"

    def shoot2():
        ball.direction = "stop"

    def shoot1():
        if ball.direction == "up":
            y = ball.ycor()
            ball.sety(y+0.5)




    #binds
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(right, "d")
    wn.onkeypress(left, "a")
    wn.onkeypress(shoot, "space")






    while True:

    #goal moving
        sl.setx(sl.xcor() + sl.dx)
        sp.setx(sp.xcor() + sp.dx)
        p.setx(p.xcor() + p.dx)

    #goal borders check


        if sl.xcor() > 250:
            sl.setx(250)
            sl.dx *= -1

        if sl.xcor() < -390:
            sl.setx(-390)
            sl.dx *= -1

        if sp.xcor() > 390:
            sp.setx(390)
            sp.dx *= -1

        if sp.xcor() < -250:
            sp.setx(-250)
            sp.dx *= -1

        if p.xcor() > 320:
            p.setx(320)
            p.dx *= -1

        if p.xcor() < -320:
            p.setx(-320)
            p.dx *= -1



    #ball and goal check
        if (ball.ycor() > 270 and ball.ycor() < 280) and (ball.xcor() < p.xcor() + 50 and ball.xcor() > p.xcor() -40): 
            score += 1
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score:{} Miss:{} ".format(score, miss), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
            shoot2()
            ball.goto(0, -275)


        if ball.ycor() > 295:
            miss += 1
            ball.goto(0, -275)
            score = 0
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score:{} Miss:{} ".format(score, miss), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
            shoot2()










        shoot1()
        wn.update()
```

Comment: What object do you want to speed up?

Comment: @Alderven sl sp p - those objects create the goal. sl is left slop, sp is the right one and p is the middle

Comment: Why not just increase the value of `sd`? Increasing this will increase how much the goal moves by each time therefore speeding up the movement.

Comment: @scotty3785 Yes, but I want the goal to change the speed after score to make it more difficult over the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a program like this, the fewer objects you try to move in real time, the better.  Your goal is three pieces that have to be be moved in unison.  The primary fix below is to define the goal as a turtle shape so the goal is only one piece that needs to be manipulated.  The secondary fix below is to replace `while True:`, which has no place in an event-driven world, with a timed event:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

sd = 1.0

FONT = ("Courier", 24, "normal")

def right():
    ball.forward(20)

def left():
    ball.backward(20)

def shoot():
    ball.direction = "up"

def shoot2():
    ball.direction = "stop"

def shoot1():
    if ball.direction == "up":
        ball.sety(ball.ycor() + sd * 2)

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("karne")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(False)

wn.register_shape("goal", ((-90, 30), (90, 30), (90, -30), (70, -30), (70, 10), (-70, 10), (-70, -30), (-90, -30)))

# pilka

ball = Turtle("circle")
ball.color("green")
ball.speed('fastest')
ball.penup()
ball.sety(-275)
ball.direction = "stop"

# scoring

pen = Turtle(visible=False)
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()

# poprzeczka

p = Turtle("goal")
p.color("white")
p.speed('fastest')
p.seth(90)
p.penup()
p.sety(270)
p.dx = sd

score = 0
miss = 0

# binds
wn.onkeypress(right, "d")
wn.onkeypress(left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(shoot, "space")
wn.listen()

def move():
    global score, miss

    # goal moving
    p.setx(p.xcor() + p.dx)

    # goal borders check

    if p.xcor() > 330:
        p.setx(330)
        p.dx *= -1
    elif p.xcor() < -330:
        p.setx(-330)
        p.dx *= -1

    # ball and goal check
    if 270 < ball.ycor() < 280 and ball.distance(p) < 50:
        score += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score:{} Miss:{} ".format(score, miss), align="center", font=FONT)
        shoot2()
        ball.goto(0, -275)
    elif ball.ycor() > 295:
        miss += 1
        score = 0
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score:{} Miss:{} ".format(score, miss), align="center", font=FONT)
        shoot2()
        ball.goto(0, -275)

    shoot1()

    wn.update()
    wn.ontimer(move, 25)

move()

wn.tracer(True)
wn.mainloop()
```

Plus lots of other little fixes to streamline the code.